# Docker and PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output.svg'

Tags: python, docker

I have a flask app and a function where I'm creating an svg file. Everything works as it should when I'm running locally, but using Docker I keep running to this error:

```
  File "app.py", line 91, in get_svg
    svg_f = open("output.svg", "w+")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output.svg'
```

First I thought the problem was with the path, but since I'm only writing to the current directory this should suffice (tried with absolute path and probably all other possible options).

The function has just the standard way of opening a file and writing to it.

```
svg_f = open("output.svg", "w+")
svg_f.write(f'<svg width="{w}" height="{h}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">')
....
svg_f.close()
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: My guess is that the file is already created in docker container, and the current user does not have permission to write it. Inside the container, run `ls -al`.  Please check the file permissions first. If you still can't figure it out, include the result in your question and output of `id`.

Comment: I assume (a) you're writing `output.svg` to a bind-mounted volume; (b) your container is running as a non-root user. If so, the Flask process is likely running as 'other'. You may test this by `chmod o+w` on the host (!) directory that's mounted to the container.

Comment: I'm not writing `output.svg` to any volume, I'm only creating it temporarily and then using `os.remove('output.svg')` since I only need to pass it through the api and then I'm done with it. I know that docker does not store any persistent data, but it should handle this right?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `Dockerfile` isn't specifying [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) that may not have permission to write in your [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir). The comments are also relevant (mounted volume and container running as a low priv user). Here's a simple image example for a baseline you can use to debug with.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
COPY app.py /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["/app/app.py"]
```

app.py

```py
w = 1
with open('output.svg', 'w+') as fw:
    fw.write(f'<svg width="{w}"')

print('Success!')
```

Showtime

```sh
$ docker build -t edd/so_q .
...magic...
$ docker run edd/so_q
Success!
```

Comment: Hmm, I pretty much have the exact same set up, but I keep running to the provided premission error.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Fedora 32, I had to disable SELinux temporarily.

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```